# Are $\sup_n |\Re a_n|<a\in \mathbb R, \sup_n|\Im a_n|<+\infty$ and $|a_n|<a\ \forall n\in\mathbb N $ in contradiction?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider a sequence of complex numbers $a_n\in \mathbb C$. Prove that (or prove otherwise if it is not true) the (1)-(2) is in contradiction:
$$\sup_n |\Re a_n|<a\in \mathbb R, \ \ \ \ \ \ \sup_n|\Im a_n|<+\infty\ \ (1)$$
$$|a_n|<a\ \ \ \  \forall n\in\mathbb N \ \ (2)$$

Comment: The locus of points where a_n can be is described by the two conditions. They are in contradiction iff the loci do not overlap. Can you think of a sequence of $a_n$ that satisfy both conditions, which is to say, can you make a sequence that stays in both the regions?

Comment: for example, if $a_n$ is in $\mathbb R$ for all $n$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) implies (1), but (1) does not necessarily imply (2):

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1): If $|a_n|<a$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, then $\sqrt{\Re(a_n)^2+\Im(a_n)^2}<a$, and hence $|\Re a_n|<a$ and $|\Im a_n|<a$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

(1) $\not\Rightarrow$ (2): Take $a=1, a_n=2i$. Then $|\Re(a_n)|=0<1=a$ and $|\Im(a_n)|=2<\infty$, but $|a_n|=2>1=a$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Good! Then aren't (1) (2) in contradiction?

Comment: I won't say that they are in contradiction. Maybe (2) is stronger than (1)...